# No IP obtained on Edimax EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I've installed Raspbian Jessie today and I'm having problems with an Edimax EW-7811Un 802.11n that was working under Raspbian Wheezy. It shows up fine with lsusb and sudo iwlist wlan0 shows my Wifi network (broadcast from Asus RT-AC68U) but ifconfig indicates the device isn't connecting with and obtaining an IP from the router.

Anybody have similar issues or solutions? Outputs below.

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

network={
    ssid=“network”
    psk=“key”
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}

**/etc/network/interfaces**

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at this answer : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip

Comment: *"I've installed Raspbian Jessie"* -> Yes, then you changed the default settings.  Why?  If the duplicate does not solve your problem, please add details to explain **how and why** you modified things and **what you expected** your changes to accomplish.

Comment: Thank, yes. I took a look a the http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip link and returned /etc/network/interfaces to the default. I'm confident of the SSID and wifi key in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and dhcpd.conf i haven't touched at all. I tried a second wifi device (Raillink) and that show up with lsusb and scans normally, but again doesn't get an IP. I'm setting up headless. No problems at all on eth0.

Comment: I'm just trying to get wlan0 working on dhcp. I don't want a static ip.

Comment: Issue solved. I think it was issue caused by Edimax dongle being in the USB port during Jessie setup. I re-installed without the dongle present and the device found an IP as soon as I set the SSID and key in wpa_supplicant.conf and rebooted.